# App does not appear on windows store?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I created an App with Windows Universal Platform.I filled all the details that are required and submitted. It shows it passed the certification and published into store. However I do not see that app in the list and nor I can find it by searching keywords. Only exact searching  shows the app.I even changed the region in pc and searched too and it yielded in no result.

Did I miss something during submission process which is hiding app.?

Comment: Did you include keywords in your app submission?

Comment: Yes. I filled all the given slots for keywords. This is my first time creating an app and submitting it.

Comment: I updated the submission and yet nothing changed. So nobody know what is happening? I asked in Microsoft forums too but didn't got any reply.

Comment: At this point you should contact support. It doesn't sound like this problem is common enough that other folks have encountered it.

Comment: Someone just asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562587/app-missing-from-windows-10-store). The response they got from Microsoft is that it may be due to their change in search algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Published into store doesn't means that it certain to show in the Popular List unless your App has lots of User.
Can find it by keyword-searching means your App appear on Windows Store;

Comment: My app name is Pic Download. It will only appear if I search for either Pic or download. It won't appear for any other search keywords. I am not talking about top lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently how MS is handling store apps. Evidently, searches only do title searches and seem to ignore keyword searches. See this thread:

[dev-centerlistings-whats-the-point-in-keywords?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a3ce97f1-69ce-4070-b6d9-f1e2c900419b/dev-centerlistings-whats-the-point-in-keywords?forum=wpsubmit&prof=required)

Microsoft's standard reply is to reference a page describing [Changes to Store listing and search algorithms](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/24/changes-to-store-listings-and-search-algorithms/) which tells you nothing except that they've changed their search algorithms. Either that, or they tell you to open a ticket that gets you nowhere.

Looks like if you want your app to show up in a search, include your search terms in the app title (e.g., "RSS News Reader Google AOL MSN Verge WindowsCentral News"). How lame.